# Find the integral of $f(x)$ where if $x \in Q$ then $f(x)=1/x$ and if $x \notin Q$ then $f(x)=0$, from 0 to 1.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The title explains the question.
But about the efforts I made:

I tried to consider an $\epsilon$ and divide $\epsilon$ to 1 to n equal parts and prove that the biggest area in each part may equal to the value of $1/x$ in the beginning of the part times the length of it which is always $1/n$ and calculate it and set n to go to infinity and $\epsilon$ to near zero and see the result is the same as the area for the smallest sum those rectangles which is always zero.(since the lowest value of function in that part is zero) But after that I realized that all my efforts were useless since the area I was going to calculate is $-ln(\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon$ reaches zero the result would reach $+\infty$ which is not what we want.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What integral? Riemann, improper Riemann, Lebesgue, otherwise...?

Comment: Riemann integral (proper integral)